# Error al descargar documento PDF

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

Resulta que estoy tratando de abrir un documento que descargo desde mi base de datos, pero al momento me de bajarlo me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya verifique que sirven los archivos, no se que mas hacer, agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar. El codigo que tengo es este:

```html
if($_GET){
  $id = "";
  $contenido = "";
  $tipo = "";
  require_once "conexion.php";
  $id = ($_GET['id']);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE codigo_archivo = $id";
  $dwn = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  var_dump ($dwn);
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($db)){
   $file = mysqli_fetch_array($dwn);
   $nombre = $file['nombre'];
   $type = $file['tipo'];
   $size = filesize($file['nombre']);
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Content-type: application/pdf', true);
   header('Content-Type: application/forced-download');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachent; filename="' .$nombre .'"');
   header('Content-Length: $size');
   readfile ($contenido);
  } else {
   //Escribir error y redireccionar a crear-activicades.php
  }
 }
```

Agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran con este error

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

el var_dump($dwn) te puede corromper los datos del archivo. Pero de todas formas, nunca estableces el patch del archivo en la variable $contenido para llamar readfile.

Comment: Pero es que el archivo lo tengo dentro de mi bd como lo haria